# what if a python unicode object has been decoded incorrectly

Tags: python, string, unicode, character-encoding

I have a unicode variable, say unicodeVar. For example, 
`u'\xea\xb1\xb8\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\x8d\xb0\xec\x9d\xb4 \xeb\xaf\xb8\xeb\x8b\x88\xec\x95\xa8\xeb\xb2\x94 3\xec\xa7\x91' .`

This is how it looks like when i simply type unicodeVar in console.
In fact, this is the representation of 걸스데이 미니앨범 3집. yeah! it's korean. Apparently, this variable is incorrectly decode into unicode.
And i never get this in my program using unicodeVar. What display above is the result of

```
'\xea\xb1\xb8\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\x8d\xb0\xec\x9d\xb4 \xeb\xaf\xb8\xeb\x8b\x88\xec\x95\xa8\xeb\xb2\x94 3\xec\xa7\x91'.decode('utf-8')
```

If i do this: `unicodeVar.decode('unicode-escape')`, the result is a string with double slash.
Like `'\\xea\\xb1\\xb8\\xec\\x8a\\xa4\\xeb\\x8d\\xb0\\xec\\x9d\\xb4 \\xeb\\xaf\\xb8\\xeb\\x8b\\x88\\xec\\x95\\xa8\\xeb\\xb2\\x94 3\\xec\\xa7\\x91'`

Question is, how can I get the correct representation from variable way? That means using only unicodeVar?

Comment: How'd you get that value into the variable in the first place? Ideally you should fix the part of your program that gets that in the first place, instead of trying to reencode it afterwards... :)

Comment: It's return value of a function, in pyquery module. It seems that nothing's wrong with that function: It's like, PyQuery(#title).html()

Comment: @prehawk, Where is the `#title` come from? Seems like the library that fetch the content of the webpage does not handle encoding(charset) correctly, or the webpage itself lacks encoding information.

Comment: @falsetru Yeah! It's a library name pyquery. the webpage is encoded in utf-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode the string using `latin1` encoding to get bytes intact. Then decode it using correct encoding (`utf-8` for this case):

```
>>> s = u'\xea\xb1\xb8\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\x8d\xb0\xec\x9d\xb4\xeb\xaf\xb8\xeb\x8b\x88\xec\x95\xa8\xeb\xb2\x94 3\xec\xa7\x91'
>>> print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))
걸스데이미니앨범 3집
```

### Why is this happened?

Some part of your program (or library) treated utf-8-encoded bytes as `latin1`, decoded it using `latin1` instead of `utf-8`. You'd better to change that part.

```
>>> utf_8_bytes = u'걸스데이미니앨범 3집'.encode('utf-8')
>>> utf_8_bytes.decode('latin1')
u'\xea\xb1\xb8\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\x8d\xb0\xec\x9d\xb4\xeb\xaf\xb8\xeb\x8b\x88\xec\x95\xa8\xeb\xb2\x94 3\xec\xa7\x91'
```

Comment: It works! And more questions, is that all unicode like this u'\xea\xb1', is the result of wrongly decode, and how you know it's definetly encoded as latin1 not others?

Comment: @prehawk, Without context, I'm not sure what that unicode mean. If you can read Korean, reading [this post](http://openlook.org/blog/2007/04/19/cb-1167/) will be helpful.

Comment: So it's not a common way, right?. Is there any suggestion of commonly deal with incorrectly decode unicodes. I'm not sure if I will encounter other charset in chinese or japan or something else.

Comment: @prehawk, As mentioned in the answer, make the library to decode the content with correct encoding.

Comment: @prehawk, If the library can't get encoding information by itself, and it accepts some kind of `encoding/charaset` parameter, pass the encoding explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that string without `u` at start dont add `u` in beginning, just decode it with utf-8 encoding to get unicode string:

```
>>> print '\xea\xb1\xb8\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\x8d\xb0\xec\x9d\xb4 \xeb\xaf\xb8\xeb\x8b\x88\xec\x95\xa8\xeb\xb2\x94 3\xec\xa7\x91'.decode('utf-8')
걸스데이미니앨범 3집
```

Comment: If OP has a byte string and terminal encoding is UTF-8, OP dont't need to decode it.

Comment: It's not a literal string, it comes from a variable. Sorry you don't hit it. :)